# why I get java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent

Tags: java, android

I had this problem :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
>   parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

This is my code :

```
public void fillFormules(List<Category> objectsTextToShow)
    {

        LinearLayout layoutItemDetail = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layoutItemDetail);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.mygallery);
        linearLayout.removeAllViews();
        for (int j = 0; j <objectsTextToShow.size() ; j++) {
            ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(getActivity());
            scrollView.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);
            scrollView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            for (int i = 0; i < objectsTextToShow.get(j).getItems().size(); i++) {
                LinearLayout separator = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
                LayoutParams separatorParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 80);
                TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
                LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                textView.setBackgroundColor(colorUtils.titleColor);
                textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                //textView.setTypeface(FONT_TITLE);
                textView.setTextSize(28);
                textView.setText(Check.Languages(objectsTextToShow.get(j).getItems().get(i).getName(), LANGUAGE_ID));
                separator.setLayoutParams(separatorParams);
                linearLayout.addView(separator);
                linearLayout.addView(textView);

                scrollView.addView(linearLayout);
            }

            layoutItemDetail.addView(scrollView);


        }


//      scrollView.addView(linearLayout);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line

```
scrollView.addView(linearLayout);
```

to initialize `linearLayout` you are using `findViewById` which implies that `linearLayout` has already a parent, violating this way the constraint that every view can have only one parent

Comment: I add  **linearLayout.removeAllViews();**, so it's not correct what I did, right ?

Comment: it is not. The parent is `layoutItemDetail`

Comment: even though it doesn't make sense at all. If you probably want to re-think what you are doing there

Comment: Thank's you save my life.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add any `View` to another `View` if the child `View` already has a parent.

In your situation you should create `LinearLayout` programmatically, the way you have created your `ScrollView`

Do this

```
public void fillFormules(List<Category> objectsTextToShow)
{
    LinearLayout layoutItemDetail = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layoutItemDetail);
    LinearLayout linearLayout;

    for (int j = 0; j <objectsTextToShow.size() ; j++) {
        linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL); // or VERTICAL as per your needs
        ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(getActivity());
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
```